# Initializing a Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web-Project from a unit-test-project in donetCore 3.0 fails

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit-3.0

I got a pretty simple dot-net-core Project. This includes a little MockServerLibrary based on kestrel, that returns some simple REST-replies in unittests.

The complete setup works fine on dotnetCore2.2. Switching to dotnetCore3.0 produces an error in the startup of the Server:

```
Output stream: Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at ServerMock.RestMockStarter.RunServer(String[] args)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
```

*but only*, if this is done by the `[OneTimeSetup]` of the unit-test project. When I start the MockServer's `main`-Method stand alone, the server starts fine.

My Assumption is, that the Server-Start fails, because the ServerMock is a

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
(...)
```

but the unitTestProject is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
(...)
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.11.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.15.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
(...)
```

This seems not to a problem in 2.2, because we needed a explicit reference to the packages in the ServerMock

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml" Version="2.2.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

As far as I understand, these refereces aren't needed anymore (far more: the need to be removed with 3.0), but it seems that they can't be loaded automatically, when started from my unit tests.

Maybe the error is already, that the ServerMock is directy referenced by the unitTest-Project:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\ServerMock\ServerMock.csproj" />
```

and the ServerStart is pretty hard-wired in the `[OneTimeSetup]`:

```
await RestMockStarter.RunServer(null);
```

I already tried to change the type of the unitTest-Project to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, but then it's not longer possile to start/see any unitTests (at least with Rider, so I think this is not the way I should try to fix the problem)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem:

(1) Changed the ServerMock-project's `csproj`-file to

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Properties" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

From that point I assume it became a "usual" dot-net-core project, and with `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` the references to the web-extensions are again explicit.

(2) Added

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to the unit-test's `csproj` too.

(3) On that point it became al litte frustrating, because the error still occured, but [deleting the bin/obj-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41159937/4994931) then suddenly helped.